# How to call every object in adapter?

Tags: android, onclick, android-arrayadapter, checkboxlist

I have a list of array adapters that have the following layout which contains checkbox, textview increase, textview count, and textview decrease :
[layout product adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR89V.png).
what the problem is how to call or implement clicklistener from ProdukActivity.java on each object that appears on the adapter. I just want to know how does it work with object in adapter so i can count the product price in every checkbox is checked.

Here is my adapter code :

```
public class ProductAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<ProductModel> productItems;

    public ProductAdapter(Activity activity, List<ProductModel> productItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.productItems = productItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return productItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return productItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_produk, null);

        CheckBox namaProduk   = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_productName);
        TextView kurangProduk = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.decrease_product);
        TextView hitungProduk = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.count_product);
        TextView tambahProduk = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.increase_product);
        TextView hargaProduk  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);

        ProductModel produk = productItems.get(position);
        namaProduk.setText(produk.getProduct_name());
        hargaProduk.setText(produk.getProduct_price());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

and here is my ProdukActivity.java :

```
public class ProdukLaundry extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

ActionBar actionBar;
ListView listProduk;
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeProduct;
List<ProductModel> productList = new ArrayList<ProductModel>();
ProductAdapter productAdapter;
int success;
AlertDialog.Builder dialog;
RadioButton radioReguler, radioExpress;
TextView tvTotal;
Button next;
String product_id, laundry_id, product_name, product_price, service_type;
private int offset = 0;
private static final String TAG = ProdukLaundry.class.getSimpleName();

private static String url_select     = Server.URL + "selectproduk.php";

public static final String TAG_PRODUCT_ID    = "product_id";
public static final String TAG_LAUNDRY_ID    = "laundry_id";
public static final String TAG_PRODUCT_NAME  = "product_name";
public static final String TAG_PRODUCT_PRICE = "product_price";
public static final String TAG_SERVICE_TYPE  = "service_type";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS      = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE      = "message";

int countcheckBox = 0;
int totalCount = 0;
boolean regular = true;
boolean express = false;
boolean checkBox = false;

Transaction transaction;

String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_produk);

    // menghubungkan variablel pada layout dan pada java
    listProduk   = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_produk);
    swipeProduct = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swipeProduct);
    radioExpress = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio_express);
    radioReguler = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio_regular);
    tvTotal      = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.total);
    next         = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_next);
    actionBar    = getSupportActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    laundry_id = getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_LAUNDRY_ID);

    // untuk mengisi data dari JSON ke dalam adapter
    productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(ProdukLaundry.this, productList);
    listProduk.setAdapter(productAdapter);

    // menampilkan widget refresh
    swipeProduct.setOnRefreshListener(this);

    swipeProduct.post(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       swipeProduct.setRefreshing(true);
                       productList.clear();
                       productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                       callProduct();
                   }
               }
    );

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    productList.clear();
    productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    callProduct();
}

public void onClick(View view){
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.increase_product:
            countcheckBox++;
            changeCheckBox();
            hitung();
            break;

        case R.id.decrease_product:
            if (countcheckBox>0){
                countcheckBox--;
                changeCheckBox();
                hitung();
            }
            break;

        case R.id.button_next:
            save();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_regular:
            if (checked) {
                regular = true;
                express = false;
                hitung();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.radio_express:
            if (checked){
                regular = false;
                express = true;
                hitung();
            }
            break;
    }
}

public void changeCheckBox(){
    tvTotal.setText(countcheckBox+"");
}

public void hitung(){
    int totalCount = 0;
    int expressCost = 20000;
    int harga = Integer.parseInt(product_price);

    if (checkBox){
        if (express){
            totalCount+=(harga+expressCost)*countcheckBox;
        }else{
            totalCount+=harga*countcheckBox;
        }
    }

    this.totalCount = totalCount;
    tvTotal.setText(this.totalCount+"");
}

private void save() {
    if (tvTotal.getText().toString().equals("0")){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Choose Service.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    String transId = "variabel transaksi id";
    String uid = "variabel produk id";
    String type;
    if (regular) {
        type = "regular";
    } else {
        type = "express";
    }

    transaction = new Transaction(transId, uid, type);
    if (checkBox) {
        transaction.setCheckBox(String.valueOf(countcheckBox));
    }
    transaction.total = String.valueOf(totalCount);

    /*Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("transaction", transaction);
    startActivity(intent);*/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add listener for every object like below, inside `getView` of adapter. And inside the listener, do your handling

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_produk, null);

    final CheckBox namaProduk   = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_productName);
    TextView kurangProduk = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.decrease_product);
    TextView hitungProduk = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.count_product);
    TextView tambahProduk = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.increase_product);
    TextView hargaProduk  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);

    ProductModel produk = productItems.get(position);
    namaProduk.setText(produk.getProduct_name());
    hargaProduk.setText(produk.getProduct_price());

    namaProduk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
            new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    if(isChecked){
                        //check here
                    }
                }
            }
    );

    kurangProduk.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //do your task here
                }
            }
    );

    hitungProduk.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //do your task here
                }
            }
    );

    tambahProduk.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //do your task here
                }
            }
    );

    hargaProduk.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //do your task here
                }
            }
    );

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Hello Touhidul Islam, I have followed your way, but I got a problem when I pressed for example TextView INCREASE on one of the lists, I found that TextView COUNT on other lists increased. is there a solution so that I can find which list position that I press when i implement setOnClickListener?

Comment: @SenaDwijaTenaya `getView` has a parameter, position, indicating the item's position in adapter